# Substituting a list comprehension solution for numpy isin

Tags: python, list, performance, list-comprehension, isin

For some time I have been trying to make a slow part of my comet program run faster. I have a line as follows

s1=np.isin(secondsplit,file2new)

secondsplit is a numpy array. On average its about 600 x 600 in size and full of floats.
file2new is a list of floats, typically 300-700 in size.

I discussed this on the stack exchange forums and was offered a solution using list comprehension and the conversion of file2new into a set to speed things up.
My test code on a small scale worked and the list comprehension was 5x faster. The problem came when I scaled up and changed the comet program to use lists in the same way. With the greater amounts of data it ran 4x slower for that piece of code!

It was suggested that I should make a large scale example for people to look at which I have done. I am now posting it here as there have not been many people in the help forums today.

```
import numpy  as np
import timeit

mylist=[]
for i in range (0,700):
    mylist.append(i)


myarray = np.empty((600, 600))
for x in range (0,600):
    for y in range (0,600):
        p=y+(x*0.25)
        myarray[y,x]=p

myarray=np.asarray(myarray)


# object here is to produce an array of 600 x 600 with True/False values depending 
# on whether elements in myarray are in mylist.
# The question is - what ia thw fastest way to do so? Note that all array values and
# mylist values are floats. There must be an exact match. One 
# can't use isclose because it is slower 
    
    
# Example 1 - using isin (loop of 10000 used for timing illustration)

starttime = timeit.default_timer()

for i in range (0,10):
 s1=np.isin(myarray,mylist)

print (s1[0][0:10])
print (s1[1][0:10])
print (s1[2][0:10])

print("The time difference is :", timeit.default_timer() - starttime)
   
# Example 2- using list comprehension and conversion of mylist to a set (it runs way 
# slower without set conversion)

def quickisin(array,mylist):

    mylist=set(mylist)
    
    p=[]
    t=len(array)
    
    for j in range (0,t):
        h=array[j]
        s1 = [item in mylist for item in h]
        p.append(s1)
    
    q=np.asarray(p)
     
    return q    

starttime = timeit.default_timer()

for i in range (0,10):
    s1=quickisin(myarray,mylist)

 
print (s1[0][0:10])
print (s1[1][0:10])
print (s1[2][0:10])

print("The time difference is :", timeit.default_timer() - starttime)
```

As you can see the first part of the code sets up example variables. I have used myarray and mylist to make things easier for people to understand. myarray is the 600x 600 array and mylist is a list of size 700, all floats.

The expected output should be a numpy array the same size as myarray but with True and False values. Every 4th item will be True.

When run the output generated was as follows.

```
runfile('C:/A/untitled7.py', wdir='C:/A')
[ True False False False  True False False False  True False]
[ True False False False  True False False False  True False]
[ True False False False  True False False False  True False]
The time difference is : 0.5151480000000674
[ True False False False  True False False False  True False]
[ True False False False  True False False False  True False]
[ True False False False  True False False False  True False]
The time difference is : 2.0399810999999772
```

My question, and your challenge should you choose to accept it, is to use list comprehension to make the quickisin function faster than the use of numpy's isin. The prize for the fastest list comprehension solution is bragging rights.

Please note that the matches between the floats in the array and the list must be exact so the use of isclose is ruled out.

Thanking you

Comment: You can replace your for loop by a list comprehension like this: `p = [[item in mylist for item in h] for h in array]` but I'm afraid you can expect to gain much from this. It seems to me that there is not so much thing that can be optimized in your code and that the use of list comprehension won't help you here.

Answer (score 1):

[Update]: I made a mistake in the generation of the test `myarray` (had temporarily reduced size) during writing of the code and forget to reset some values. It is fixed now. My variant shows now less impressive results but is faster nevertheless.

I agree with qouify that list comprehensions won't help. Therefore I show another numpy solution which is faster than the original one but may need more memory.

Basic idea is to sort `mylist`, use the bisectional `np.searchsorted` to find nearest value less or equal and finally check if it is really equal.

I have appended it as `quickisin2` function:

```
import numpy  as np
import timeit

mylist=[]
for i in range (0,700):
    mylist.append(i)


myarray = np.empty((600, 600))
for x in range (0,600):
    for y in range (0,600):
        p=y+(x*0.25)
        myarray[y,x]=p

myarray=np.asarray(myarray)


# object here is to produce an array of 600 x 600 with True/False values depending 
# on whether elements in myarray are in mylist.
# The question is - what ia thw fastest way to do so? Note that all array values and
# mylist values are floats. There must be an exact match. One 
# can't use isclose because it is slower 
    
    
# Example 1 - using isin (loop of 10000 used for timing illustration)

starttime = timeit.default_timer()

for i in range (0,10):
 s1=np.isin(myarray,mylist)

print (s1[0][0:10])
print (s1[1][0:10])
print (s1[2][0:10])

print("The time difference is :", timeit.default_timer() - starttime)
   
# Example 2- using list comprehension and conversion of mylist to a set (it runs way 
# slower without set conversion)

def quickisin(array,mylist):

    mylist=set(mylist)
    
    p=[]
    t=len(array)
    
    for j in range (0,t):
        h=array[j]
        s1 = [item in mylist for item in h]
        p.append(s1)
    
    q=np.asarray(p)
     
    return q


def quickisin2(array,mylist):

    mylist=np.sort(mylist)
    shape = myarray.shape
    myarrayflat = np.reshape(myarray, -1)
    foundindices = np.searchsorted(mylist, myarrayflat)
    foundindices[foundindices >= mylist.shape[0]] = 0
    
    foundarray = mylist[foundindices]
    mask = myarrayflat == foundarray

    return np.reshape(mask, shape)



starttime = timeit.default_timer()

for i in range (0,10):
    s1=quickisin(myarray,mylist)

 
print (s1[0][0:10])
print (s1[1][0:10])
print (s1[2][0:10])

print("The time difference is :", timeit.default_timer() - starttime)




starttime = timeit.default_timer()

for i in range (0,10):
    s1=quickisin2(myarray,mylist)

 
print (s1[0][0:10])
print (s1[1][0:10])
print (s1[2][0:10])

print("The time difference is :", timeit.default_timer() - starttime)
print("The time difference is :", timeit.default_timer() - starttime)
```

On my machine with Python 3.7 64bit I get (last one is the new way):

```
[ True False False False  True False False False  True False]
[ True False False False  True False False False  True False]
[ True False False False  True False False False  True False]
The time difference is : 0.26915568
[ True False False False  True False False False  True False]
[ True False False False  True False False False  True False]
[ True False False False  True False False False  True False]
The time difference is : 1.052180994
[ True False False False  True False False False  True False]
[ True False False False  True False False False  True False]
[ True False False False  True False False False  True False]
The time difference is : 0.1133786440000002
```

Comment: Thank you. That has halved the prcessing time of that bit of code for me which will save me a lot of time.
Could cuda somehow be used to make it faster still?